# getElementsByTagName does not return comment nodes in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to retrieve all the nodes present in particular DIV element.see the below test page
(firefox)

```
 <HTML>
 <HEAD>
  <TITLE> New Document </TITLE>
  <META NAME="Generator" CONTENT="EditPlus">
  <META NAME="Author" CONTENT="">
  <META NAME="Keywords" CONTENT="">
  <META NAME="Description" CONTENT="">
 <script>
 function processTags()
 {
    var chNodes = document.getElementById('foo').childNodes ;
console.log(chNodes);   
console.log("------");  

  var chNodes = document.getElementById('foo').getElementsByTagName('*') ;
 console.log(chNodes); 
}
</script>
 </HEAD>

 <BODY onload="processTags();">
  <div id="foo">
  <!-- this is a comment -->this is some text ? <span>this is inside span</span>
  <div><p>test</p>test<div>
  </div>
 </BODY>
</HTML>
```

But it does not give me comments tag.. what is the best way to retrieve all tags ??

Comment: BTW nobody does all-caps HTML element names anymore. Just sayin'. ;)

Comment: @Tomalak: maybe it was a copy-pasted and slightly modified `innerHTML`/`outerHTML`? :-P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The heart of the problem is that these methods...

```
document.getElementById(...)
document.getElementsByTagName(...)
```

... return *elements*, as indicated by their names. However, comments and text nodes are not elements. They are nodes, but not elements.

So you need to do some traditional old fashioned DOM scripting, using `childNodes` like Vincent Robert suggested. Since - as you indicate in your comment to him - that `.childNodes` only goes one 'layer' deep, you need to define a recursive function to find the comment nodes: (I'm naming mine `document.getCommentNodes()`)

```
document.getCommentNodes = function() {
    function traverseDom(curr_element) { // this is the recursive function
        var comments = new Array();
        // base case: node is a comment node
        if (curr_element.nodeName == "#comment" || curr_element.nodeType == 8) {
            // You need this OR because some browsers won't support either nodType or nodeName... I think...
            comments[comments.length] = curr_element;
        }
        // recursive case: node is not a comment node
        else if(curr_element.childNodes.length>0) {
            for (var i = 0; i<curr_element.childNodes.length; i++) {
                // adventures with recursion!
                comments = comments.concat(traverseDom(curr_element.childNodes[i]));
            }
        }
        return comments;
    }
   return traverseDom(document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0]);
}
```

Comment: Have you tested this in IE? The MSDN documentation for [childNodes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537445\(v=VS.85\).aspx) states that it only returns HTML elements and TextNode objects via childNodes.  The documentation for [nodeType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534191\(v=VS.85\).aspx) corresponds with this, showing the possible values as `1 (Element)` or `3 (TextNode)`.  Food for thought...

Comment: @Andy E's head - No, I didn't! I took for granted it would work in IE as I'd used something similar to find text nodes before :( Good call.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.childNodes` to retrieve all children instead of `.getElementsByTagName('*')` which will only return child elements.

Here is a function to retrieve all descendants of a DOM node:

```
function getDescendantNodes(node)
{
    var ret = [];
    if( node )
    {
        var childNodes = node.childNodes; 
        for( var i = 0, l = childNodes.length; i < l; ++i )
        {
            var childNode = childNodes[i];
            ret.push(childNode);
            ret = ret.concat(getDescendantNodes(childNode));
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Usage:

```
getDescendantNodes(document.getElementById("foo"));
```

Comment: @Sourabh - Then it's time for adventures with recursion!

Comment: added a recursive version to retrieve all descendants of a node

Answer (score 3):

If you don't care about IE, you could avoid the recursive approach and possibly improve performance (untested) by using a [`TreeWalker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/TreeWalker) using [`document.createTreeWalker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createTreeWalker):

```
function getCommentNodes(containerNode) {
    var treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(containerNode,
        NodeFilter.SHOW_COMMENT, null, false);
    var comments = [];
    while (treeWalker.nextNode()) {
        comments.push(treeWalker.currentNode);
    }
    return comments;
} 

console.log(getCommentNodes(document.body));
```

Answer (score 1):

Node types (non exhaustive):

- Element
- Text
- Comment

`getElementsByTagName` only picks up Element nodes. `childNodes`, `nextSibling`, etc. pick up all kinds of nodes. `nextElementSibling` only picks up Elements.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use the innerHtml and then use a parser to find the comments in it.

Comment: This is an interesting idea; since comments can't be defined inside themselves, they could probably be exracted/parsed much more easily than fully parsing HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Comments are nodes in the DOM tree, but they don't have a tag name. The `getElementsByTagName` method only returns nodes that have a tag name.

If you want all nodes, you have to traverse the DOM tree, using the `childNodes` collection of each element.

Answer (score 0):

```
var getComments = function(oNode) {
    var oChild,
        aComments = [];
    oNode = oNode || document;
    for (var n=0; n<oNode.childNodes.length; n++) {
        oChild = oNode.childNodes[n];
        switch (oChild.nodeType) {
            case 1: // Element
                aComments = aComments.concat(getComments(oChild));
                break;
            case 8: // Comment
                aComments.push(oChild);
                break;
        }
    }
    return aComments;
}
```