# How to resolve document.body.innerHTML.replace conflict?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using javascript to hide everything between two html comment tags but when I use this code on my page some other javascript gets messed up. I need help to fix my code so it does not conflict with others.

```
<!-- start html comment --> remove me <! -- end html comment -->


document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/\<\!\-\- start html comment -\-\>((.|[\n|\r|\r\n])*?)\<\!\-\- end html comment -\-\>[\n|\r|\r\n]?(\s+)?/g, "");
```

Comment: what code gets messd up? do yuo have an error?

Comment: I am using this code in my Wordpress admin area. When this code is present I am not able to expand menu items when mouseover a menu on the left. No errors in the consol.

Comment: Replacing `innerHTML` will remove any event listeners registered on the original elements. The better option would be to use DOM methods to remove the targeted elements

Comment: The content that I am removing/hiding does not have a class or id. So I am not able to target it.

Comment: Then you just access it by finding sort of nodes. If you override `innerHTML`, the whole contents is re-written so everything you did on the children of the target element, must be reset.

Comment: @noobtw: Please, don't add irrelevant tags.

Answer (score 0):

Using reduced code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912710/getelementsbytagname-does-not-return-comment-nodes-in-javascript#2912981) question DOM version.

```js
var page = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0];
removeComments(page);
console.log(document.body.outerHTML);

function removeComments(curr_element) { // this is the recursive function
  // base case: node is a comment node
  if (curr_element.nodeName == "#comment" || curr_element.nodeType == 8) {
    // You need this OR because some browsers won't support either nodType or nodeName... I think...
    console.log(curr_element.data);
    curr_element.parentNode.removeChild(curr_element);
  }
  // recursive case: node is not a comment node
  else if (curr_element.childNodes.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < curr_element.childNodes.length; i++) {
      // adventures with recursion!
      removeComments(curr_element.childNodes[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<UL>
<LI>1st<!-- HTML comment 1 --></LI>
<LI>2nd</LI><!-- HTML comment 2 -->
</UL>
```

Comment: Thank you for the example but this code does not remove content between the two tags ie: <!-- start --> remove me <! -- end -->

Comment: Not so hard to change and there is no other way to modify content without breaking other functionality, but using DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is an extra space in your example:

```
<!-- start html comment --> remove me <! -- end html comment -->
//                              here ___^
```

I've removed it in my solution.

Use this regex:

```
<!-- start html comment -->[^]+?<!-- end html comment -->\s*
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/2oDPTi/1)

Your code becomes:

```
document.body.innerHTML = 
  document.body.innerHTML.replace(/<!-- start html comment -->[^]+?<!-- end html comment -->\s*/g, "");
```

Comment: How would I use that on my page?

Comment: @Mel: just replace your regex by this one in `document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(......)` see my edit.

Comment: But wouldn't that still cause issue that I am referring too?

Comment: @Mel: Well, I don't know the content of the whole page, but have you tried my solution? Does it work?

Comment: your code did not work but did cause the issue that I was referring to. The problem is innerHTML. Any way to do this with Jquery?